# Duplicate oracle database from remote server on local machine

Tags: oracle11g, duplicate-data

Plz someone help me.

I have an oracle 11g running on a remote server, and I need make a copy on my machine to work out of the networking.

I have access on remote sever with *sys as sysdba*. With that user I make an export with SQLDeveloper. The I install oracle on my machime and try run the files of the export. But I get a lot of error, and the SQLDeveloper lost the connection.

How can I duplicate remote server database on my machine?

Comment: use either rman active clonning or impdp over db link. it depends whether you need to clone the whole database or just a schema(s).

Comment: I need duplicate whole database. But I have access only by DB. When i read about **rman** I see that I need create new directories, but i don't have access. Is there any mode to do this only using 2 connections? One on remote server and other on local?